# How to create custom TabControl Directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently using Zurb Foundation 4 for my CSS/Grid Framework and they have a really nice Tab Control. However, when it is on a page that is loaded via ng-view the tab control doesn't work right.

So, I'd thought I'd write my own directive since I will be using this across our site. However, once I got into it I soon realized I was in over my head.

I've provided an example of what I am trying to do and then an example of my actual mess of code

Static example: Here is what I am trying to accomplish. See full code example on JsFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/aYTaN/1/

```
<div class="tab-container">

    <p class="active-tab">
        <a href="">Tasks</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="">Parts</a>
    </p>

    <section>
        Tab 1 content
    </section>

    <section style="display:none">
        Tab 2 Content
    </section>

</div>
```

Here's the actual code I have that is not working:
http://jsfiddle.net/dxwc9/3/

```
app.directive('tabControl', function($rootScope) {
    'use strict';

    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log(attrs.tabs);

            var tabs = attrs.tabs.split(',');

            var tabContainer = angular.element('<div class="tab-container"></div>'),
                tab = angular.element('<p><a href=""></a></p>'),
                content = angular.element('<section></section>');

            for (var i = 0; i<tabs.length; i++){

                tabContainer.append(tab);

                var title = tab.find('a');

                title.html(tabs[i]);

                tabContainer.append(content);

            }


        }


    }

});
```

I would really appreciate any help please.

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The angularui/bootstrap project has a very simple implementation with tabs and panes (your sections equivalent). Check it out on **[Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js)**

The basic idea is creating two directives (one for the tabs, and one for the sections) and having a common controller communicate between them.

Comment: The tabs has been updated to tab-set, which is a bit more complicated on the code side, but the same concepts still apply with having a common controller.